# i have built jQuery animate image.animate jQuery is not working on second click

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation

```
$( "#btn1" ).click(function() {

   var $this = $(this);
   var clickCount = ($this.data("click-count") || 0) + 1;
   $this.data("click-count", clickCount);

    if (clickCount%2 == 0) {
        $("#img1").hide('clip').animate({
            marginLeft: "40%"

        },1500);
    } else {
        $("#img1").show('clip').animate({
            marginLeft: "40%"
        },1500);
    }

});
```

problem is the first time j query animate is proper working when i hide the image and then click third time click on button i want to same animate as first time but it is faster and not working properly.

**[working example](http://jsfiddle.net/mohsin80/y5devv2j/)**

Comment: working example :http://jsfiddle.net/mohsin80/y5devv2j/

Comment: place your html and js in different section of fiddle.

Comment: You are clicking button before animation complete. You can disable button while animation runs and enable it after animation complete. You can see my answer with working demo [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32709898/i-have-built-jquery-animate-image-animate-jquery-is-not-working-on-second-click/32710080#32710080)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/huseyinbabal/y5devv2j/7/)**

That speed problem caused by clicking button before animation finish. You can prevent it by disabling button when click button and then re-enable it after animation complete. Also, it will be better if you reset style after each animation complete. You can have a look at code below.

```
$("#btn1").click(function() {
var button = $(this);
button.attr("disabled", true);
var $this = $(this);
var clickCount = ($this.data("click-count") || 0) + 1;
$this.data("click-count", clickCount);

if (clickCount % 2 == 0) {
    $("#img1").hide('clip').animate({
        marginLeft: "40%"

    }, 1500).promise().then(function() {
        button.removeAttr("disabled");
    });
} else {
    $("#img1").removeAttr('style');
    $("#img1").show('clip').animate({
        marginLeft: "40%"

    }, 1500).promise().then(function() {
        button.removeAttr("disabled")
    });
}
```

});

Comment: working demo:-http://jsfiddle.net/mohsin80/4ww8efx5/2/
hey Huseyin BABAL in this demo work fine in desktop but in mobile device dragging of magnifier is not work.help me

Comment: @MohsinKureshi could you please raise another question about that problem? Thanks

Comment: @BABAL i did but i didn't get the solution for that

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/GaganJaura/y5devv2j/2/. Its working

```
$( "#btn1" ).click(function() {

   var $this = $(this);
   var clickCount = ($this.data("click-count") || 0) + 1;
   $this.data("click-count", clickCount);

    if (clickCount%2 == 0) {
       $("#img1").hide('clip').animate({
    marginLeft: "0px"

    },1500);
    }
    else
    {
        $("#img1").show('clip').animate({
    marginLeft: "200px"

    },1500);
    }

});
```

Comment: working demo:-jsfiddle.net/mohsin80/4ww8efx5/2 hey Man Programmer in this demo work fine in desktop but in mobile device dragging of magnifier is not work.help me

Answer (score 1):

Try this http://jsfiddle.net/y5devv2j/4/

```
if (clickCount%2 == 0) {
       $("#img1").hide('clip').animate({
    marginLeft: "0%"

    });
    }
    else
    {
        $("#img1").show('clip').animate({
    marginLeft: "40%"

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Your working [jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2mLu7chp/1/). Your animation speed is fast. so you have to increase the time for animation.

```
if (clickCount%2 == 0) {
   $("#img1").hide('clip').animate({
marginLeft: "0px"

},2500);
}
else
{
    $("#img1").show('clip').animate({
marginLeft: "40%"

},2500);
}
```